# How to remove line breaks with PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript

I've tried about everything to delete some extra `\n`  characters in a web application I'm working with. I was hoping someone has encountered this issue before and knows what can be causing this. All my JS and PHP files are UTF-8 encoded with no BOM.

And yes I've tried things like

In JS:

```
text.replace(/\n/g,"")
```

In PHP:

```
preg_replace("[\n]","",$result);
str_replace("\n","",$result);
```

and when I try

```
 text.replace(/\n/g,"")
```

in the firebug console using the same string I get from the server it works but for reason it doesn't work in a JS file.

I'm desperate, picky and this is killing me. Any input is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

If it helps, I know how to use the replace functions above. I'm able to replace any other string or pattern except `\n` for some reason.

**Answer Explanation:**

Some people do and use what works because it just works. If you are like me and for the record I always like to know why what works WORKS!

In my case:

Why this works?   `str_replace('\n', '', $result)`

And this doesn't?   `str_replace("\n", '', $result)`

Looks identical right?
Well it seems that when you enclose a string with a character value like `\n` in double quotes `"\n"` it's seen as it's character value NOT as a string. On the other hand if you enclose it in single quotes `'\n'` it's really seen as the string `\n`. At least that is what i concluded in my 3 hours headache.

If what I concluded is a setup specific issue OR is erroneous please do let me know or edit.

Comment: Are you actually storing the result from text.replace()? It doesn't replace the contents of the existing variable, it makes a new one.

Comment: "[Please Read]" ? I don't think that's gonna work.

Comment: Did you try \u patter modified (i.e. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8)? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: The line break might be `\r\n` as well. If you only remove one half, it might still be interpreted by browsers. Maybe even try `[\r\n\v]`.

Comment: @mario i came down to the conclusion that at least in JS `[\r\n\v]` is not working because the '\n' shows up in the browser so is a string and `[\r\n\v]` looks for the character value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php, use `str_replace(array('\r','\n'), '', $string)`.

I guess the problem is you also have `\r`'s in your code (carriage returns, also displayed as newlines).

Comment: Read the `Answer Explanation` edit and see why this works and others solution don't even though they looked like they should :)

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, the `.replace()` method doesn't modify the string. It returns a new modified string, so you need to reference the result.

```
text = text.replace(/\n/g,"")
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the case

Comment: If it helps, i know how to use the replace function. I'm able to replace any other pattern or string but '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Both of the PHP functions you tried return the altered string, they do not alter their arguments:

```
$result = preg_replace("[\n]","",$result);

$result = str_replace("\n","",$result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the case

Comment: try: $result = preg_replace( "#\n|\r|\r\n#", '', $result);

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, using

```
str_replace(array('\r','\n'), '', $string)
```

didn't work for me. I can't really work out why either.

In my situation I needed to take output from the a WordPress custom meta field, and then I was placing that formatted as HTML in a javascript array for later use as info windows in a Google Maps instance on my site.

If I did the following:

```
$stockist_address = $stockist_post_custom['stockist_address'][0];
$stockist_address = apply_filters( 'the_content', $stockist_address);
$stockist_sites_html .= str_replace(array('\r','\n'), '', $stockist_address);
```

This did not give me a string with the html on a single line. This therefore threw an error on Google Maps.

What I needed to do instead was:

```
$stockist_address = $stockist_post_custom['stockist_address'][0];
$stockist_address = apply_filters( 'the_content', $stockist_address);
$stockist_sites_html .= trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $stockist_address ) );
```

This worked like a charm for me.

I believe that usage of \s in regular expressions tabs, line breaks and carriage returns.